# Bundledoc tool showing error in OS Windows 7

Tags: errors, miktex, texlive, windows

As per the documentation of bundledoc, I have used a simple Tex file as mentioned in the document

```
\RequirePackage{snapshot}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, world! \ref{sec2}
\end{document}
```

Where it produces a file `hello.dep`. The content generated inside the `hello.dep` are:

```
\RequireVersions{
  *{application}{TeX}     {1990/03/25 v3.x}
  *{format} {LaTeX2e}     {2011/06/27 v2.e}
  *{package}{snapshot}    {2002/03/05 v1.14}
  *{class}  {article}     {2007/10/19 v1.4h}
  *{file}   {size11.clo}  {2007/10/19 v1.4h}
}
```

I ran the following command

```
bundledoc --config=miktex.cfg hello.dep
```

but it produces the below mentioned error

```
initexmf: --find-latex-input: unknown option
bundledoc: "initexmf --find-latex-input %BDINPUTS%" (BDINPUTS="hello.tex") failed to find hello.tex
```

Can anyone please guide me how to solve this error.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: I wonder if the `miktex.cfg` file is still valid.  It uses the option `--find-latex-input` to the MikTeX command `initexmf`, but that command is not listed (was it ever?) as an option here: [http://docs.miktex.org/manual/initexmf.html](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/initexmf.html) -- which certainly explains the `unknown option` complaint.  Perhaps you should post this on `comp.text.tex`, where the package author is more likely to read this (or email him directly).  Unfortuantely, I don't use MikTeX or windows, so I can't test this, but I can confirm that `bundledoc` is great.

Comment: The `man` page also says that this was only tested on Windows NT and MikTeX, which sounds like the testing happened some time ago.  Perhaps `initexmf` did remove some other options..?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

The package is absolutely outdated in regard to the provided configuration file, as already noticed by Jon in a comment. As the error messsage shows, does the used command `--find-latex-input` not work and is not even mentioned in MiKTeX documentation anymore.

To get back the function one has to create an own file. Below I will provide one here. By the way: As it turned out, *also TeX Live for Windows is affected.*

#### First

Users of MiKTeX have to download a command line tool `zip.exe`, in TeX Live this is already included. So, as MiKTeX user go to ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/win32/, download the latest `zipXXX.zip` and extract at least the contained `zip.exe` into a folder that is included in the system path. (A note on other archive programs in post scriptum.)

#### Second

Open your favorite text editor and paste the following in

```
# bundledoc configuration file for TeXing in Windows,
# by Steffen "Speravir" Hoffmann, licence LPPL,
# source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159012/9237
#
# Derived from configuration files provided with program
# package by Scott Pakin 

# ASSUMPTION: You have "zip" somewhere in your path, and it accepts the
#             command-line options utilized by the "bundle" line below.

bundle: zip -r -v -9 %BDBASE%.zip %BDINPUTS%
sink:   > NUL 2>&1
find:   kpsewhich -progname=latex $BDINPUTS
```

Save it as `wintex.cfg` or whatever you want somewhere in your local TeXMF root (MiKTeX users: user maintained root, cf. [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/)). Pay attention, that you do not accidentally save with file extension `.txt`.

As experienced users will notice, this is actually built together from provided configuration files, but it works meanwhile in Windows.

#### Third

Make an update of your filename data base (FNDB). Then you can use the file with the `--config` option. MiKTeX users should know, though, that a Perl interpreter must be separately installed in Windows, cf. [MiKTeX and Perl scripts (and one Python script)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158796/).

---

PS: In theory you can use every archive program, that works on command line. You would have to adjust the line starting with `bundle` in the config file. But there is one caveat: The variables `%BDBASE%` and `%BDINPUTS%` expand to a string surrounded by double quotes *(change the `bundle` line to `bundle echo %BDBASE% %BDINPUTS%` and execute `bundledoc` with this changed version and you will see)*. The archiver must be able to deal with this. In a test with `7z`, the commandline version of 7-Zip, I was not successful, other programs I couldn't test.