# How to compile glossaries with arara without Perl?

Tags: glossaries, arara

I don't want to install Perl. I am using arara for building. I make use of the glossaries package.

Can I compile my document without the `makeglossaries` help script (I don't want to install Perl)? I use biblatex as well.

Currently my arara directives look like this:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex
% arara: clean: {files ... blah blah
```

Where would I need to put the glossary compilation command? Does it have to be before or after xelatex compilation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Should be able to add `makeglossaries` anywhere between the two `xelatex` lines.

Comment: @MikeRenfro If I'm not mistaken, `arara` doesn't *replace* any of the programs it fires off—it merely provides a convenient way to do so.  OP seems to be asking for a non-Perl `makeglossaries`, which is unlikely to exist, unfortunately.  That said, I *really* doubt that you don't have Perl installed, OP.  *So* many things use it in TeX distributions—it's often just included.  (Just because it isn't in your `PATH` doesn't mean it's not there `:)`)

Comment: Hm... I am pretty sure it's not installed (I am using Miktex). But from what I understand makeglossaries is simply a wrapper around makeindex. I guess I want to run that directly. Is this not a standard practice? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if there's anyway of accessing the base file name within an arara directive, but if your file is called, say, `test.tex` then you can do `% arara: makeindex: {style: test.ist, options: "-t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo"}`

Comment: @Nicola, please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

cmhughes's answer is best for general purposes, but you can also just use the `makeindex` directive however you need to explicitly write the file names. If your LaTeX file is called `myDoc.tex` then the following will work:

```
% arara: makeindex: {style: myDoc.ist, options: "-t myDoc.glg -o myDoc.gls myDoc.glo"}
```

(Avoid spaces in the file names.) That will just create the `main` glossary. If you've used the `acronyms` option you will need to have a similar line for the list of acronyms:

```
% arara: makeindex: {style: myDoc.ist, options: "-t myDoc.alg -o myDoc.acr myDoc.acn"}
```

Similarly if you have additional glossaries (either created explicitly via `\newglossary` or via other package options such as `index`).

If you want to sort by letter order instead of word order you need to add `-l` to the options list.

(The advantage of the `makeglossaries` script is that it reads the `.aux` file to find out which glossaries the document has defined, what their corresponding file extensions are, and whether to use `makeindex` or `xindy`. TeX Live comes with its own Perl interpreter. The only inconvenience is for MiKTeX users, but [MiKTeX and Perl Scripts (and one Python script)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158796/miktex-and-perl-scripts-and-one-python-script) provides instructions for MiKTeX.)

*Edit:* `arara` v4.0 has a [`makeglossarieslite` rule](https://github.com/cereda/arara/blob/master/rules/makeglossarieslite.yaml) which can be used to invoke `makeglossaries-lite.lua`, the Lua alternative to `makeglossaries`. Since LuaTeX requires a Lua interpreter, one should already be available with modern TeX systems.

Although `makeglossaries-lite.lua` doesn't have the full set of functions that `makeglossaries` has, it still has the advantage of being able to pick up the glossary information from the `.aux` file that an explicit call to `makeindex` can't do and so will work with any number of custom glossaries defined within the document.

Answer (score 8):

Following [Nicola Talbot's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot) comment, and the output from [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara), we know that the `makeglossaries` rule is really just a short cut for:

```
makeindex -s myfile.ist -t myfile.glg -o myfile.gls myfile.glo
```

As such, we can make an [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) do this for us by using `@{getBasename(file)}`.

## `makeglossariesNP.yaml`

```
!config
# Make glossaries *without perl* rule for arara
# author: Chris Hughes
# last edited by: cmh, March 3rd 2014
# https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163474/how-to-compile-glossaries-with-arara-without-perl
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample usage
#
# % arara: makeglossariesNP
#
identifier: makeglossariesNP
name: makeglossariesNP
commands: 
- <arara> makeindex -s @{getBasename(file)}.ist -t @{getBasename(file)}.glg -o @{getBasename(file)}.gls @{getBasename(file)}.glo
arguments: []
```

## `myfile.tex`

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: makeglossaries
% arara: makeglossariesNP
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{equation}{name=equation,description={an equation usually involves at least one variable, and 
has two sides; typically we will try and solve an equation for one of the unknown variables}}
\newglossaryentry{expression}{name=expression,description={an expression usually involves at least one variable--
    in contrast to an equation, an expression does not have two sides, and will often need to be simplified (not solved)
in some way}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way of adapting this rule to specify alternate extensions for `.glg` / `.gls` / `.glo` (e.g. `.alg` / `.acr` / `.acn` for the acronym list)?

Comment: Is there any way to specify this directly in .tex file without the additional yaml file?

Comment: Sadly, this solution is rather cumbersome, as it requires me to add my project location to the search path for the rules. The original comment by Nicola is, while admittedly less general, is much simpler and convenient.

Comment: whoever down voted, please detail why

Comment: @cmhughes Sorry, I downvoted not because the answer is bad, but because the approach is currently not viable because arara has o way of discovering rules in the *local* directory. I prefer the other approach of hard-coded inline directives. I shouldn't have downvoted in retrospect --- I was only doing so comparative to the other possibility.

Comment: @drozzy `arara` rules can be put in different directories and you can specify those directories in a `arara-config` file. Please refer to arara manual.