# Makeindex warning

Tags: miktex, glossaries, indexing

During `\makeglossaries` run I get warning:

> Process started: makeglossaries "settings"
>
> makeglossaries version 2.12 (2014-01-20)
>     added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)
>     makeindex  -s "settings.ist" -t "settings.glg" -o "settings.gls" "settings.glo"
>
> WARNING: Unable to fork "makeindex": Bad file descriptor Retrying without redirection. This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning style file C:/Users/asus/Downloads/settings.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored). Scanning input file settings.glo....done (1 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting entries...done (0 comparisons). Generating output file settings.gls....done (6 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written in settings.gls. Transcript written in settings.glg.

Process exited normally

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gloss}{
name=glossaries,
description=A package for generating glossaries in many styles
}

\begin{document}
\texttt{\gls{gloss}} is a great package!ds
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

How this warning can be avoided?

What is wrong with my settings?

Comment: At first start with [MiKTeX and Perl scripts (and one Python script)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158796).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

This isn't an error or anything wrong with your settings. You're just using an operating system that doesn't support `makeglossaries`'s preferred method of running `makeindex`/`xindy` so it uses a platform independent approach instead. The next version of `glossaries` (4.04) will include a new version of `makeglossaries` (2.14) that will have a new `-Q` switch which you will be able to use to suppress the warning. (I plan to upload the new version to CTAN in the next few days, but I need to make a few modifications to the user guide first.)

**Technical Answer:**

`makeglossaries` tries to run `makeindex`/`xindy` by forking the application using the `2>&1 |` piped redirection. It does this for two reasons:

1. `makeindex`/`xindy` don't put all their error messages in the transcript file. This method grabs both the messages in the standard output stream and the errors in the standard error stream so that `makeglossaries` can check for common errors and provide a suggested fix.
2. This is the only way for `makeglossaries`'s `-q` option to work properly.

Not all operating systems support this method of running an application, so if this fails, `makeglossaries` falls back on a simpler way of running the application and then parses the transcript file afterwards, but it means that you won't get as many diagnostic messages if things go wrong and the `-q` option may not be as quiet as you might expect.

However, if the `makeindex`/`xindy` run is successful and you're not bothered about suppressing their messages, you don't need to worry about it.

**Update:**

I've uploaded `glossaries` version 4.04 to CTAN. This has the new `makeglossaries` version 2.14 which provides two new switches: `-Q` (suppresses this warning) and `-k` (prevents `makeglossaries` from trying the piped redirection method so it will only try the platform independent method). I've also added a few more diagnostic checks.