# Xindy cannot be executed

Tags: miktex, glossaries, xindy

Trying to run `\makeglossaries` after I've already compiled the file with `pdflatex` gives me the error:

`**Call to xindy failed*** Check 'settings.glg' for details`

In the file  `'settings.glg'` this is written:

`*** Unable to execute: '"xindy"  -L english  -I xindy -M "settings" -t "settings.glg" -o "settings.gls" "settings.glo"' ***`

`Status report:`

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gloss}{
name=glossaries,
description=A package for generating glossaries in many styles
}

\begin{document}
\texttt{\gls{gloss}} is a great package!
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Everything works when I use `\makeindex` (`\usepackage{glossaries}`), but with the warning.
About this warning I've already asked the question [Makeindex warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163794/makeindex-warning).

Could you explain me what I'm doing wrong with `xindy`?

P.S.

I've installed xindy using this [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71168/43831) and made settings for my TeXstudio using [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118871/43831).

Comment: Do you have MiKTeX installed as TeX distribution? I actually suspect so, see [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71167).

Comment: Oh, I see your other post [Makeindex warning](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163794). So, you _are_ using MiKTeX.

Comment: @Speravir I've used this  [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex), it did not help, I've mentioned it in my question, but not clearly.

Comment: Your minimal example works fine here (well, it’s actually mine). Note that the command on terminal is **`makeglossaries`** _without_ a backslash! In other words: You did something wrong, but I cannot say from here, what (I suspect it’s a problem of system path inclusion).