# How do I use latexdiff with MikTex without Perl given repository problem?

Tags: packages, miktex, windows, latexdiff, revision-control

The [CTAN latexdiff page](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) states that latexdiff is contained within miktex. Trying to [install it using MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin) as suggested January 14th](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165543/using-latexdiff-in-miktex), I instead encounter an error (is it a connection error?):

> MiKTeX Problem Report
>
> Message: The remote package repository is not registered. You have to choose another repository.
>
> Data: url="http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/"
>
> Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageManager.cpp
>
> Line: 1817
>
> MiKTeX: 2.9
>
> OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 14393
>
> Invokers: non-existing/explorer
>
> SystemAdmin: yes
>
> PowerUser: no
>
> Root0: C:\Users[account]\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> Root1: C:\Users[account]\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> Root3: C:\local tex files
>
> Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
>
> UserInstall: C:\Users[account]\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> UserConfig: C:\Users[account]\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> UserData: C:\Users[account]\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
>
> CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

Apparently there is no other online repository I can choose from. Is my only option to [install Perl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158796/miktex-and-perl-scripts-and-one-python-script/158797#158797) and try [Chelsea's Sept. 2016 solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165543/using-latexdiff-in-miktex) independent of miktex?

Comment: If you see only one repository the problem is in miktex. There has been a bug report about this some days ago (https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2612/)  perhaps you are affected by this too.