# Really lots of multiple indices with imakeidx - ind files not being created

Tags: imakeidx, perl

I am writing my thesis in law and need to create about 21 different indices (lists of treaties, lists of statutes, lists of cases from different jurisdictions, etc). I am using the package imakidx with splitindex, and it all works fine when I try it out on a test file with only a few indices, but as soon as I try it out on a chapter with all 21 indices it seems to get stuck.

```
 \documentclass[bibliography=totoc, a4paper]{scrbook}
 \usepackage[backend=biber, style=oscola, refsection=chapter]{biblatex} 
 \usepackage[splitindex,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
```

When I run pdflatex it shows that it starts to create the individual .ind files for each index:

```
Started index file statutes
Started index file treaties
```

but it then complains that it can't find the .ind files with the source file name, (the source file is called "Factors")

```
No file factors-statutes.ind
No file factors-treaties.ind
```

and I end up with no indices at all.

I try running splitindex and it says the Perl interpreter could not be found, even though I have Perl installed. When I compiled the shorter test file I didn't need to call splitindex - I guess this has to do with the number of index files that can be written at once.

Do I just have to resign myself that 21 indices is too many for Latex? Or is my problem more likely to be with installing Perl in a specific place? I apologise if these questions are vague!

(Please note I am not creating indices the way the Oscola package suggests since I have too many jurisdictions that do not fit under the Oscola design)

Comment: You have to run manually `splitindex` and `makeindex`, due to the `nonewpage` option. But the option is not necessary, since you're using a `book` class where the indices make chapters.

Comment: If `perl` can't be found, it would be helpful to know your OS, how you installed `perl` (or why you think it is already installed) and whether other things find `perl` OK.

Comment: @cfr - I installed Active Perl on my Windows 64-bit machine manually. It gives the option to add Perl to PATH variables, which I select on installation. When I enter the command "perl -v" in the command prompt, it tells me what version is installed. So it's there, but can't be found by Latex somehow

Comment: I guess the script is probably different on Windows so I'm not sure.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158796/miktex-and-perl-scripts-and-one-python-script help?