# rejected index entries with two separate indeces using splitidx

Tags: indexing, makeindex

My index entries get rejected.
I compile, and then in TexStudio do Tools > Commands > MakeIndex

I thought I did everything according to the [documentation](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/splitindex/splitidx.pdf).

I had no problems using makeidx.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{splitidx}

\makeindex
\newindex[Berechnen]{rech}
\newindex[Graph]{gra}


\begin{document}
    text
    \newpage
    text 1
    \sindex[rech]{lord}
    \newpage
    text2\sindex[rech]{shawty}
    \newpage
    text3\sindex[gra]{leftist}
    \printindex[rech]
    \newpage
    \printindex[gra]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get `Scanning input file buoch-gra.idx....done (1 entries accepted, 0 rejected).` for the first index and `Scanning input file buoch-rech.idx....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected).` for the second one.

Comment: I get 'This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6200] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning input file MWE.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 3 rejected). Nothing written in MWE.ind. Transcript written in MWE.ilg.' Does that provide further information? Seems ike only one .idx file is made ...

Comment: You have to run `splitindex`, not `makeindex`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `splitidx`, the correct sequence of commands is

```
pdflatex file
splitindex file
pdflatex file
```

The program `splitindex` will create the `.idx` files and then run `makeindex` over them.

Comment: How do I "run splitindex"? Windows user here :-)

Comment: @Buochserhorn Sorry for you. `;-)`. Define a new tool for TeXStudio that runs `splitindex` instead of `makeindex`.

Comment: I tried to do that, can see the splitindex package in the Miktex package manager, but still get: 'Process started: "C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/splitindex.exe"

splitindex.exe: The script could not be found.

splitindex.exe: Data: scriptEngine="perl", name="splitindex", path="scripts/splitindex/perl/splitindex.pl"' [I get the same error when I change the default index tool to splitindex, and makeindex and splitindex are in the same folder]

Comment: @Buochserhorn I think you need Perl, but I'm afraid I know nothing about Windows.

Comment: I installed that in the meantime thanks to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158796/miktex-and-perl-scripts-and-one-python-script), now only the script is missing. :-)