# Changing how letters are sorted in index

Tags: indexing, xindy

The alphabet in the albanian language is :

A B C Ç D DH E Ë F G GJ H I J K L LL M N NJ O P Q R RR S SH T TH U V X XH Y Z ZH

This is the code I am trying

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[columns=2, title=Indeks]
\indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-2] Centurion\index{Centurion} is writing something,
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} finished writing.

\kant[3-6] Çarli\index{Çarli} is writing something,
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} finished writing.

\kant[7-9] Eugen\index{Eugen} is writing something,
Genadios\index{Genadios} finished writing.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And this is the result :

[image]

The letter Ç should appear between C and D (even merged with C would be fine)

I tried  `xindy -M texindy -L turkish -C utf8 sample.idx` but xindy wasnt recognized in windows' cmd (xindy: The script engine could not be found.
xindy: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"), so I am using `makeindex sample` (MikTeX 2.9)

I hope this is not a duplicate.

Comment: You need to install Perl to get `xindy` to work (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158796). `makeindex` doesn't support UTF-8.

Comment: It worked. Is there a command to eliminate the letters A B C Ç before the words ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing Perl as suggested by Nicola Talbot and using

`xindy -M texindy -L albanian -C utf8 sample.idx` <- replace sample by your file name between compilations.