# Is there anyway to configure MiKTeX so that it locates script engine perl.exe?

Tags: miktex, latexmk

I am using MiKTeX and I keep receiving the following error from latexmk.exe even if I have done all the necessary actions to handle this: Downloaded latexmk 4.48, created a folder scripts\latexmk\perl, copied latexmk.bat & latexmk.pl in it and added in latexmk.bat the full path of the perl.exe in my PC)

Unfortunately, the error message does not indicate where is latexmk.exe looking for the perl engine -- big S/W flaw! So, how can I find where is MiKTeX looking for this script engine so that I can either move latexmk.bat & latexmk.pl in there or configure MiKTeX to look for the necessary files in scripts\latexmk\perl ?

(Added later)
Here are the 2 error message lines:

latexmk: The script engine could not be found.

latexmk: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"

(Note: I have also tried using the parent folder: scripts\latexmk. No luck! All the scripts are there. Where else is MiKTeX looking for latexmk.pl???)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: You are not writing which error you get. Why do you install latexmk manually and not with the package manager?

Comment: Oh sorry. I had in mind doing that, of course, but ...  Here are the 2 error message lines:

latexmk: The script engine could not be found.
latexmk: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"

Comment: I installed the WiKTeX package. It installed latexmk.exe but not latexmk.pl and latexmk.bat. That's why I downloaded and added them later. I have read this solution in another tex.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: Related: [MiKTeX and Perl scripts (and one Python script)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158796).

Answer (score 1):

I found that the path of perl.exe must be in environment PATH. This is the only way I could make MiKTeX's tatexmk.exe run.

So, the answer to the question is that **MiKTeX is not configuarable** as far as this issue is concerned.

Comment: If perl was correctly installed, MiKTeX should find it . Which distribution of `perl` do you have?

Comment: It's a problem that it is not configurable, when you use a portable strawberry perl distribution