# using git-latexdiff on Windows

Tags: latexdiff

I need to get the latexdiff between current git revision and 10 commits back so I am looking at this [git-latexdiff](https://gitlab.com/git-latexdiff/git-latexdiff). However the instruction seems to be for non-Windows.

I did try to run the `windows_install.cmd` file included in the instruction. But after that I run

```
git latexdiff HEAD~10 --main mymain.tex
```

or

```
git-latexdiff HEAD~10 --main mymain.tex
```

But it couldn't understand the command. How do I get the diff on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `latexdiff` is installed on your device and also check its version by running `latexdiff --version` If it is not installed properly then `git latexdiff` will also not work, since it is built around `latexdiff`. For `latexdiff` you also need to have perl installed. More info about it all can be found [here on stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158796/miktex-and-perl-scripts-and-one-python-script)